# Network connection between two laptops communication problem?

Tags: networking, macbook-pro

I have two laptops (both wifi enabled) and a wireless router. I want to use one of the laptop on a robot and other laptop to SSH into the first one. Is it possible to connect the two PCs even if I don't have a modem or internet and just use the wifi router? If so how to do that? I learned about the ad-hoc network, but I am unable to create an ad-hoc network on my macbook pro 6'2 with ubuntu 11.10, so i need an alternate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this before, but here's what you can do -

First install an ssh server on the laptop you whish to ssh to.

For ubuntu type this in the terminal -

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

And for the other laptop -

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

Type `ifconfig` on your server laptop to find out its ip address.

You can then connect to you server -

```
ssh (server IP)
```

You can add static IPs to both of your laptops so that their addresses don't change!...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how to obtain the static IP for both laptops. Will the router provide a static IP or dynamic IP ?

Comment: [Set A Static IP On Ubuntu](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu). 


Remember to backup /etc/network/interfaces before you make any  
changes.

Answer (score 0):

The wifi router will work regardless of whether you have internet. So, both laptops will be connected using the router as a common link. So, to ssh to one of them you'd use something like `ssh 192.168.1.2`. Of course, replace the IP address with the IP address of the laptop you're connecting to. You might ditch DHCP and use static IP addresses for them so that one laptop is always 192.168.1.2 and the other is always 192.168.1.3.